# Firebase Function writing undefined to Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, messagebird

I am new, let me know if anymore information is needed!

I am trying to integrate MessageBird with Firestore. It is writing everything to the database okay except for the "to" field which takes a phone number. I am logging the number and it is being output correctly in the console, except in my Firestore it is being stored as `undefined`. If anyone can provide any insight as to why this is, that would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck for some while. (Attached part of function where issue arises and screenshot of console)

I originally tried without using `await` on the `doc.data()?.phoneNum` line and just received `[object Promise]`. Now that it is printing in console I know this has nothing to do with it. Please help!

```
admin.auth().listUsers().then((res) => {
    res.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
      try {
        const dbRef = firestore()
            .collection("collection").doc(userRecord.uid)
            .collection("collection").doc(document);
        dbRef.get().then((context) => {
          if (context.exists) {
            firestore()
              .collection("collection")
              .doc(userRecord.uid).get()
              .then(async (doc) => {
                number = await doc.data()?.field1;
                console.log("Sending message to: " + number);
              });
            firestore().collection("collection")
              .doc()
              .create({
                channelId: "id",
                type: "text",
                content: {
                  text: "message",
                },
                to: `${number}`,
              });
            functions.logger.log("SUCCESSFULLY SENT TO DB");
          } else {
            // console.log("**Unviable user**");
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

[image: Google cloud console (covered the correct phone number)]

[image: Firestore output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promises doesn't seem to handled properly. `.data()` does not return a promise so you don't need an `await` there. Also I don't see the var `'number'` declared anywhere so that'd be undefined. You can try running the following code:

```
admin.auth().listUsers().then(async (res) => {
    try {
        for (const userRecord in res) {
            const dbRef = firestore()
                .collection("collection").doc(userRecord.uid)
                .collection("collection").doc(document);
            const context = await dbRef.get()
            if (context.exists) {
                const number = (await firestore().collection("collection").doc(userRecord.uid).get()).data().field1
                console.log("Sending message to: " + number);
                await firestore().collection("collection").add({
                    channelId: "id",
                    type: "text",
                    content: {
                        text: "message",
                    },
                    to: `${number}`,
                });
                functions.logger.log("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                // console.log("**Unviable user**");
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {

    }
});
```

Also `forEach` doesn't wait for promises to resolve so I've used a for-in loop.

Comment: The for-in loop seemed to be the piece I was looking for. As a novice programmer, promises confuse the hell out of me! I am new to stackoverflow, sorry if the question/my code was a riddle.